# Números aleatorios PARES entre 100 y 1000

Tags: c

necesito hacer un programa en C que muestre 50 números aleatorios PARES entre 100 y 1000, el código que tengo hecho es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int N,a;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(a=1;a<=50;a++) {
        N=rand()%101+1000)*2;
        printf("%d.- %d \n",a,N);
    }
}
```

Pero me marca error en la instrucción de rand, porque?

Comment: Te falta un paréntesis, te deje un ejemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se debe a que te falta un paréntesis:

En todo caso, en el siguiente ejemplo te muestro la forma correcta  para calcular un **numero aleatorio PAR entre 100 y 1000**.

Ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int N,a;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(a=1;a<=50;a++) {
        N=rand() % 451 *2 + 100;   /* numero aleatorio PAR entre 100 y 1000 */
        printf("%d.- %d \n",a,N);
    }
}
```